# Class 'GeoJSON' incorrectly extends base class 'FeatureGroup'

Tags: typescript, npm, leaflet, yarnpkg, gulp-typescript

In a project of mine I get this error message:

```
test/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts(856,11): error TS2415: Class 'GeoJSON' incorrectly extends base class 'FeatureGroup'.
  Types of property 'setStyle' are incompatible.
    Type '(style: StyleFunction) => this' is not assignable to type '(style: PathOptions) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'style' and 'style' are incompatible.
        Type 'PathOptions' is not assignable to type 'StyleFunction'.
          Type 'PathOptions' provides no match for the signature '(feature?: Feature<GeometryObject>): PathOptions'.
```

Here are the input files:

test.ts

```
import { LatLngExpression } from 'leaflet'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.0.68",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "test.ts"
  ]
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");

const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task('default', () => {
    const tsResult = tsProject.src().pipe(tsProject());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});
```

The error appears if I execute "yarn && gulp" - but not, if I use "npm install" instead of yarn, and not if I use "tsc -p ." instead of the gulp file.
Furthermore, as long as I had Typescript 2.4.1 there was no error at all - it appeared after I updated to Typescript 2.4.2.

I would like to report this as a bug - but I don't know what part is responsible: yarn, typescript, gulp-typescript, @types/leaflet?

How could I get hold of this?

Obviously I extracted this test case from a larger project where I would like to use "yarn && gulp", which leads to the error. So I would like to have a fix - not any of the "workarounds" above.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems this has been fixed "automagically". My guess is, there was an inconsistency between repositories of npm and yarn.

Hard to tell - and probably useless. So this question might be closed or deleted.

Comment: I do have the same problem, so I guess the question should stay.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced a similar issue after upgrading Typescript from version 2.4 to 2.5 as well. Updating the @types/leaflet module solved the issue for me.

```
npm update @types/leaflet
```